# ComboBox Silverlight 5 auto search not working when using the TwoWay "Binding"

Tags: silverlight, combobox, binding, silverlight-5.0, two-way-binding

The `ComboBox` seems to face a problem when the data binding happen. The auto text search is not working. Need help here. Do not know what the actual problem is or if I missed out something.

```
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="121,84,0,0" Name="cbxDock"
  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="281" SelectionChanged="cbxDock_SelectionChanged"
  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" DataContext ="delivery_dock_cde">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path= delivery_dock_cde, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <TextBlock Text=" - " />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding delivery_dock_dsc,Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: <ComboBox  
HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
Margin="121,84,0,0" Name="cbxDock"  
VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="281" 
SelectionChanged="cbxDock_SelectionChanged" 
Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" 
DataContext ="delivery_dock_cde">

<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                
<DataTemplate>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

<TextBlock Text="{Binding  Path= delivery_dock_cde, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<TextBlock Text=" - " />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding delivery_dock_dsc,Mode=TwoWay}" />

</StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

</ComboBox>

Answer (score 1):

add this to the combobox declaration or to the code item:

```
TextSearch.TextPath="delivery_dock_dsc"
```

And it won't do the auto search until the combobox is dropped down.